# Android Deep Linking - Verify App links with website

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-deep-link

I am trying to enable deep linking with my app 
I need when I scan the QR from outside my app like using **QR Scanner** app or using QR scanner in the system, and when I choose the web browser and search with the link, it directs to my app 
I added the code to manifest like this image:

[image]

and when I searched with https://domain.ex/.well-known/assetlinks.json

[image]

and searched with https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://domain.example&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

[image]

what is the error I had made?

I am running one release mode and SHA256 is from google play console.

**expected behaviour is:** when I search with https://domain.example/pathPrefix it direct to my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need to add scheme separately

```
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />

    <data
        android:host="yourdomain.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/prefixpath/" />

</intent-filter>
```

If the above steps don't work, please try changing the name of the website in the URL given below, which will show you the SHA256 key google has been cached.

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://www.your-website-name.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

See this [How to force Google to refetch .well-known/assetlinks.json in order to fix my Android App Link implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510142/how-to-force-google-to-refetch-well-known-assetlinks-json-in-order-to-fix-my-an)

Comment: Why need to add <data android:scheme="http" />? Why need to separate?

Comment: It's also not working for me

Comment: @GeorgeSamuel I just corrected my answer. Please see my last solution. Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the code successfully worked when I pushed the code to internal testing on google play console, then download the app, it worked fine.
to run the code on release mode isn't enough to do the correct behavior.